# New CentOS 7 server - Sending mail from a PHP application

Tags: php, email, smtp, configuration, centos7

Apologies for the newbie question but i'm hoping someone can provide me with some help/steps.

I am in the process of migrating a website from a managed shared hosting account online to a new **CentOS 7** cloud server. Everything seems to be working perfectly apart from when it tries to send emails from the PHP scripts. When setting up the CentOS server I did not configure any mail apps etc..

I am assuming this is because I haven't installed something. Would anyone be able to advise how I can set up the server to send emails from the PHP app *(I do not want to setup a full mail server as this is managed through Office365)*.

I tried sending a test and all it does it post a message to me in ***/var/spool/mail***

Any help/advice would be great! *(Output from /var/spool/mail/ below)*

---

```
--0AEF.1434711105/testserver1.localdomain
Content-Description: Delivery report
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns; testserver1.localdomain
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 0AEF
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; apache@testserver1.localdomain
Arrival-Date: Fri, 19 Jun 2015 06:51:44 -0400 (EDT)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; chris@gmail.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0
Remote-MTA: dns; googlemail.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-Verification failed for
    <apache@testserver1.localdomain> 550-The mail server could not deliver mail
    to apache@testserver1.localdomain.  The account or domain may not exist,
    they may be blacklisted, or missing the proper dns entries. 550 Sender
    verify failed

--0AEF.1434711105/testserver1.localdomain
Content-Description: Undelivered Message
Content-Type: message/rfc822

Return-Path: <apache@testserver1.localdomain>
Received: by testserver1.localdomain (Postfix, from userid 48)
    id 0AEF; Fri, 19 Jun 2015 06:51:44 -0400 (EDT)
To: chris@gmail.com
Subject: My subject
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:index.php
Message-Id: <0AEF@testserver1.localdomain>
Date: Fri, 19 Jun 2015 06:51:44 -0400 (EDT)
From: apache@testserver1.localdomain (Apache)


First line of text
Second line of text

--0AEF.1434711105/testserver1.localdomain--
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll still need to configure *something* to deal with email.

The easiest way is probably to configure whatever MTA you're using so that it changes `apache@testserver1.localdomain` (the email address that php ends up using) into whatever mail address you want to use.

Since you seem to be using Postfix, you should check out [this](http://www.postfix.org/SOHO_README.html#fantasy) part in the official Postfix documentation which explains how to do that.

Comment: Hi Wouter, thank you for the quick response. I followed the instructions on the page you suggested and tried again but still no luck. Im new to this so im not certain I have done it correctly

Comment: Please explain what exactly you did and how it failed. Can't expect help if you don't show what you're doing.

Comment: I edited the **/etc/postfix/main.cf** file to contain **smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic**. I then editing the  **/etc/postfix/generic** file and added in the local address it was using and supplied the correct one EG. **his@localdomain.local             hisaccount@hisisp.example** I then saved the files and ran **postmap /etc/postfix/generic** Do I need to have a domain pointing to the server before doing this? At the moment it just has is public IP as provided by the cloud provider.

Comment: You don't necessarily need a domain pointing to the server. However, your server must be allowed to send mail *from* the domain that you're using. That is, the domain must exist, and the domain must not have an SPF record (or if it does, the server must be listed as one of the permitted senders). Otherwise your mail is likely to be dropped by the receiving server as spam.

Answer (score 0):

Wouter is correct to say that you need an mta, and that postfix is a good choice, however before spending a lot of time configuring it, you should check that your efforts will not be in vain.

- can your server resolve hostnames (try with nslookup)?
- can it make connections to the outside world on port 25 (try with telnet)?
- is selinux enabled?

Disabling selinux might seem a bit clumsy and ill-advised but, while the RH7 type policy is an improvement on 6.5, SElinux and the RH policy are truly horrible and add very little security benefit at a horrendous cost in terms of effort on anything other than a static content server.